# Make an array without separation/line showing between

Tags: modifiers

I need help figuring out how to model something and use an array with it on the Z axis so it repeats smoothly.. 
It doesn't seem to do what i want when I apply a glass material.
I can't seem to figure it out exactly but any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a picture of what exactly your model is like, or a blend file would help us answer the question more fully.

Comment: you nailed it right on the head. thank you, i feel dumb for not seeing that but I appreciate you so much Uncle Snail. Really new to using Blender stack exchange so idk if I was able to select your answer as correct but you're based af. Thanks :)

Comment: Yup, you did everything right. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try enabling *"merge"* in the modifiers panel.

[image]

You can also try *"first last"*, which will merge vertices from the first object and the last object in the array. (A circle for example.)

Make sure you set the *merge distance*.

[image]

Hope this helps you out.